# Is it possible to calculate force acting on water in electric field?

Tags: electric-fields, water, polarization

I know, that when water is placed in an electric field a force is acting on it because of polarization. Is it possible to calculate this force with taking the brownian rotation of the molecules as well as the intermolecular interaction (in fluid state) into account? Are there any experimentally measured constants/coefficients for that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Water can be treated as a dielectric with dielectric constant $\approx$ 80

Comment: Note that water (i.e. tap water, with lots of ions) is not only a dielectric but also a conductor. In an electric field the water will have a non-zero charge distribution. The force caused by this charge is, to my knowledge, considerably stronger than the force cause by the polarization of the water molecules.